# Is there a way to know what iteration an Airflow sensor is on?

Tags: airflow

Say I have created a custom Sensor in Airflow, which repeats every 30 seconds like so (code is within the main DAG file):

```
my_sensor = MyCustomSensor(
    task_id='my_sensor',
    poke_interval=30,
    timeout=43200, # 12h
    mode='poke',
    dag=dag
)
```

Here's the boilerplate for my custom sensor in the plugins folder:

```
class MyCustomSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
   
   ...

   def poke(self, context):
      # How can I know here if it's the 1st iteration of poke, the 3rd, etc?
```

How can my sensor code know what iteration (of poke) is currently running? For example if I want to take a specific action on the 1st poke, or every 5th poke, is there any way to do that?

I looked for something in the context variable but so far I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class variable that would always be incremented when poke is called. That way you can access that class variable via, e.g., `MyCustomSensor.my_class_var` and see what number is there.

```py
class MyCustomSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    my_class_var = 0

    ...

    def poke(self, context):
        MyCustomSensor.my_class_var += 1
        ...
```

NOTE: For others who have come across this post, see comments for discussion about class variable use case vs instance variable use case.

Comment: Haha thanks, I feel a bit stupid for not thinking of that. Although, wouldn't it be safer to use an instance variable (i.e. defined in `__init__`) in case I use the sensor multiple times in a DAG? I just tested and that works too.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, that would be probably safer in terms of having a separate variable for each instance of the class if you want to track the number of runs for that particular instance only. In case you need to track the total number of runs on multiple instances, the class variable is the way to go, as it is only one and always increases when running the method at any given instance of the class.